# How to find files based on array

Tags: shell, array

I have an array that contains a list of filenames (without extension)
ex:

```
filearray=("fileA" "fileB" "fileC")
```

These files are split amongst multiple directories.  As I loop through the directories, I would like to perform an operation on the files from the array that are present in each directory.  How can I use find or grep with an array?

Can I do something like this?:

```
Dirarray= ("dirA" "dirB")
for Dir in "${Dirarray[@]}"; do
    cd "$Dir";
    for file in "${filearray[@]}"; do
        if find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "$file"; then;
            do X;
        fi;
     done
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: You just answered your won question in the question?  Or are you having some trouble with your script?  (PS: you probably need to `cd` back after `cd "$Dir"` or use subshell)

Comment: @grochmal It looks fine to me without another `cd`. I corrected readability. One `done` was missing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say: the find statement doesn't work with the array element

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in a different way.

```
Dirarray= ("dirA" "dirB")
for Dir in "${Dirarray[@]}"; do
    cd "$Dir"
    for file in "${filearray[@]}"; do
# Here a change. If "$file" exists...
        if [[ -e "$file"]]; then
            : # do something
        fi
     done
done
```

See `man test` for more file test options.

The reason is this way is much more simple. Well, as long as the array doesn't contain regexes.

Comment: Also, `${filearray[@]/#/$Dir/}` instead of the `cd`.